# Microsoft access embedded macro onclick

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I noticed in the 2013 Microsoft Access Desktop Product inventory template (Go to New -> Desktop Product inventory template -> Explore with sample data button -> A Sample User Login -> Purchases Tab -> Click "New" in the ID column

That you will see a pop up when you click this underlined blue "(New)" text in the ID column. It's an embedded macro that fires onclick to bring up a form that was designed.

I'm trying to achieve this same exact behavior in a brand new, blank database, with only 1 table and 1 form. I can't seem to figure out how you get the clickable blue (New) text in an empty table so that it fires an onclick event macro, much less make that macro contain a call to a form.

I figured out how to create a macro. I can create a table. I can create a form. I can't seem to get the default blank table row ID column to populate with a hyperlink/embedded macro (the "(New)" text in the sample inventory database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that sample template, we achieve the blue underline hyperlink-type effect by selecting that text box control in the datasheet form (datasheet form here, not table) and selecting "Always" for the "Display As Hyperlink" control property. By default, this control property will be "If Hyperlink." Change that to "Always" and you'll see the text box control change to a blue color and be underlined. You then need to create an embedded macro or VBA code attached to the On Click event of the control.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, my first mistake was not realizing it was a datasheet form (wasn't aware of those until now)
Even if I had known though, I still wouldn't have realized to change that control property, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Good luck with your Access projects.